# Angular Universal (SSR) heap size issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, server-side-rendering

I am using **Angular universal**. There is always error in logs about *Heap out of memory*.
I have tried to unsubscribe all *subscriptions* but still facing the issue.

Currently Website acquired approx. 900 mega byte of memory. Any idea what to do?